# Failing to install llama-index package

Tags: llama-index

can you please help me with this issue (llama-index installation fails. I have the latest version of pip and almost tried everything but still getting the same error when the llama-index installation reaches this point. I am not that experienced and used VSCODE and also pycharm and still getting the same thing on both.

```
Using cached llama_index-0.4.4.post2.tar.gz (204 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done

then I receive this error:

The conflict is caused by:
llama-index 0.6.8 depends on langchain>=0.0.154
llama-index 0.6.7 depends on langchain>=0.0.154
llama-index 0.6.6 depends on langchain>=0.0.154
llama-index 0.6.5 depends on langchain>=0.0.154
llama-index 0.6.4 depends on langchain>=0.0.154
llama-index 0.6.2 depends on langchain>=0.0.154
llama-index 0.6.1 depends on langchain>=0.0.154
llama-index 0.6.0 depends on langchain>=0.0.152
llama-index 0.5.27 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.26 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.25 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.23.post1 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.23 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.22 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.21 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.20 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.19 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.18 depends on langchain==0.0.142
llama-index 0.5.17.post1 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.17 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.16 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.15 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.13.post1 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.13 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.12 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.11 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.10 depends on langchain>=0.0.123
llama-index 0.5.9 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.8 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.7 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.6 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.5 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.4 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.3 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.2 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.1 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.5.0 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.40 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.39 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.38 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.37 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.36 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.35.post1 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.35 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.34 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.33 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.32 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.31 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.30 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.29 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.28 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.27 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.26 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.25 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.24 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.23 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.22.post1 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.22 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.21 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.20 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.19 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.18 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.17 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.16 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.15 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.14 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.13 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.12 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.11 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.10 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.9 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.8 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.7 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.6 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.5 depends on openai>=0.26.4
llama-index 0.4.4.post2 depends on openai>=0.26.4

To fix this you could try to:

loosen the range of package versions you've specified
remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting version conflicts. You should do the following

Step 1 :

```
pip uninstall langchain llama-index
```

step 2 :
Install the packages with correct versions

```
pip install langchain==0.0.174 llama-index==0.6.9
```

Prerequisite : you should have python >= 3.9 to work with llama-index or langchain modules